# How do I get the inside of the network to see the server properly? Inside the network, foobar.net doesn't resolve

Tags: dns, hostname, hosts, domain, host-name-resolution

I'm running MINT 20.1.
I am connected to the net via AT&T UVERSE fiber optic.
I have a DNS, foobar.net, set up to point at my router, and when I am outside the network, I can load a website running on my server which is inside my home. From the local starbucks, it properly resolves foobar.net to my router, and I have port forwarding on for the ports I need.
When I am inside the network, foobar.net is not resolved. Now I can fix the laptop with /etc/hosts, but my android phone is a different matter. I'd like it to resolve seamlessly inside and outside the local network.
My desktop server is named "Linux-server" and I would like the network to resolve foobar.net to linux-server. I've even thought about changing the hostname to foobar.net, but I am not sure that would work.
What suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your router allows you to set up internal DNS entries, use this option
2. If your router can handle [Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/q/55611/267016) you should be able just to reference foobar.net. This will resolve to the external IP address, which your router can then map back to the internal server
3. Otherwise you're going to need to set up an internal DNS server have have your internal devices use it for name resolving. This will require some support from your router, so that as it hands out IP addresses via DHCP it volunteers that the DNS server is "over there →" rather than it being the default DNS server
4. If all else fails, get another router or device capable of routing (e.g. DDWRT or other Linux-based system), and either replace your ISP-provided router entirely, or put this extra one between your ISP-provided router and the rest of your network. (This includes disabling or avoiding use of WiFi on the ISP-provided router.) Configure items #1 or #3 on this better router and leave the ISP-provided device simply to act as a dumb endpoint

Comment: The router, an Arris BGW210 doesn't support an internal DNS entry. But I do have another wireless router that probably does, and I can check to see if that does the trick. The router does not support hairpin NAT. and Honestly, I don't think that the router will support an internal name server. I'll try the router route. Pun intended. I'll let you know.